# Simplifying expression with many radicals

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

Are there tools in Mathematica to simplify the following expression further, for $0<x<1$?

```
pdf = -((2 (-2 Sqrt[(1 - x) x] + 2 Sqrt[(1 - x) x^3] + 
         Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x - x^(3/2)] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x + x^(3/2)] - 
         Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x^3 + x^(7/2)] + 
         Sqrt[x] (-1 + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x - x^(3/2)] - 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x + x^(3/2)] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x^3 + x^(7/2)] - 
            x (-2 + Sqrt[2 - 2 Sqrt[x]] + x + 
               Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x - x^(3/2)]))))/(\[Pi] (-2 + Sqrt[
         2 - 2 Sqrt[x]] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[x]] - Sqrt[
         1 - x]) (-1 + x) x));
Assuming[{0 < x < 1}, FullSimplify[pdf]]
```

(This is the result of `PDF@TransformedDistribution[(2 x - 1)^2, x \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[3/2, 3/2]]`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

dist = TransformedDistribution[(2 x - 1)^2, 
   x \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[n/2, n/2]];

pdf[n_] = Assuming[0 < x < 1, PDF[dist, x] // FullSimplify]

(* (2^(1 - n) (1 - x)^(-1 + n/2))/(Sqrt[x] Beta[n/2, n/2]) *)
```

Verifying the validity of the distribution,

```
Assuming[n > 0, Integrate[pdf[n], {x, 0, 1}] // Simplify]

(* 1 *)

Plot[Evaluate@Table[pdf[n], {n, 1, 4}], {x, 0, 1},
 PlotLegends ->
  Table[StringForm["pdf[``]=``", n, pdf[n]], {n, 4}]]
```

[image]

```
dist3 = TransformedDistribution[(2 x - 1)^2, 
   x \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[3/2, 3/2]];

pdf3 = Assuming[0 < x < 1, PDF[dist3, x] // FullSimplify]

(* -((2 (-2 Sqrt[(1 - x) x] + 2 Sqrt[(1 - x) x^3] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x - x^(3/2)] + 
       Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x + x^(3/2)] - Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x^3 + x^(7/2)] + 
       Sqrt[x] (-1 + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x - x^(3/2)] - Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x + x^(3/2)] + 
          Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x^3 + x^(7/2)] - 
          x (-2 + Sqrt[2 - 2 Sqrt[x]] + x + 
             Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x - x^(3/2)]))))/(π (-2 + Sqrt[2 - 2 Sqrt[x]] + 
       Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[x]] - Sqrt[1 - x]) (-1 + x) x)) *)

Assuming[0 < x < 1, PossibleZeroQ[Simplify[pdf[3] - pdf3]]]

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:**

```
Assuming[0 < x < 1, Simplify[pdf[3] - pdf3]]

(* 0 *)
```

Comparing graphically,

```
Plot[{pdf[3], pdf3}, {x, 0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"pdf[3]", "pdf3"}, {.5, .5}],
 WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]